# Posting same payload on two or more pubnub channels

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

Does posting the same message payload on two or more PubNub channels increase the required network bandwidth proportionally?

We're using mobile data networks, and consequently are careful about bandwidth usage.

Comment: Jasper check out bandwidth savings by [Pipelining Messages into One TCP Packet](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/10/how-to-rapidly-publish-messages-on-pubnub).  This works great however it requires custom coding efforts on your part.  So you'll need to decide if you want to achieve this extra performance gain and bandwidth savings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each publish operation is a separate request, so yes. When you publish on multiple channels, you make multiple requests and will proportionally increase your bandwidth consumption.

Instead of publishing the same message on two channels (channel-a, channel-b), you could have another channel (channel-c). The subscribers of channel-a and channel-b will then additionally subscribe to channel-c and can receive messages meant for the combined group.

Channels are transient resources so you can create as many of them as you want - http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/494/how-many-channels-can-i-use

Comment: Girish!  What you doing talking about technology and data channels  

Comment: Jasper check out bandwidth savings by [Pipelining Messages into One TCP Packet](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/10/how-to-rapidly-publish-messages-on-pubnub)

Answer (score 0):

## Simulate multi-channel publishing with PubNub Channel Groups

Another way to *simulate* multi-channel publish is to use [Channel Groups](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/categories/channel-groups) with a temp channel. It works something like this:

1. Every client subscribes to its own unique channel group: cg_user1, cg_user2, and so on.
2. When you want to publish a message to multiple channels, you just need to know who needs to receive the message. I am going to assume you are able to determine this on the server side or pass the user list (UUIDs) to your server. So POST your message to the server (with the list of UUIDs unless you can figure this out on the server).
3. Your server then generates a temp channel (use UUID generator if you like) and then iterate through the list of users and add the new temp channel to each of the user's unique channel groups (cg_user1 and such).
4. Your server then publishes the message to the new temp channel. Now all channel groups that have that channel will receive the message.
5. Once the publish succeeds (on success of the publish) you can then remove the channel from every one of those channel groups. Or, you let the client remove the channel once the client has received the message (might be pulling the message from history or message catchup).

Yes, you are still making multiple calls to PubNub to add the channel to each channel group (might be a add channel to list of channel groups in the future) but what you are saving on is the number of published messages (reduce the message count) from the client.

You could also just POST the message to the server and let the server publish to unique channels (rather channel groups) where each channel is a private user channel. Same result but is multiple publishes with will increase your message counts, if just by a few, unless you have thousands of channels you are publishing to.